# Custom style creates incompatibility between mathtools and listings

Tags: document-classes, incompatibility

My school, the University of Rhode Island (URI),
recommends using style files developed by the school for completing theses,
such as a custom document class file, [`urithesis.cls`](http://web.uri.edu/ecbe/thesisguide/step2/),
for the `\documentclass{}` command.

I have determined that this custom document class file
creates an incompatibility between  the `mathtools` and `listings` packages.

I perused the `.cls` code and was not able to determine any obvious problems.
(*This is expected, as I am not well-versed in custom document class files.*)
I notified the owner/creator, and have not yet received a response.

Is this type of issue when using a custom document class
a common and generally easily-resolved issue?
(Both packages are highly-desirable to me.)

**MWE**:

In the above link, reiterated [here](http://web.uri.edu/ecbe/thesisguide/step2/) for convenience,
the document class file is provided, as well as a minimum working example (MWE).

Please download the `thesis.zip` link for the complete MWE.
If the following code is added to the preface of the root file `thesis.tex`:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
```

then an error message will occur.
Commenting either package out will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The class does a very wrong thing, which explodes when `calc` is loaded together with `listings`.

```
% line 424
\newcounter{chaptercitecount}

% lines 795-801
\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{chaptercitecount}{0}%
  \if@sequential%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  \else%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  \fi}
```

The `\cl@chapter` macro is executed whenever `chapter` is stepped, so as to do the required resetting. Doing `\setcounter` inside it is wrong anyway.

You have to fix the class, I'm afraid. The first bit should become

```
% Counts the number of references in each chapter to determine if there
% is a list of references for that chapter when using chapterref format.
\newcounter{chaptercitecount}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thechaptercitecount}{\arabic{chaptercitecount}}
```

and the second part should be

```
\def\cl@chapter{%
  \@elt{chaptercitecount}%
  \if@sequential%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  \else%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  \fi}
```

There are much better methods than to hook in `\cl@chapter`, though.

I'd suggest removing the redefinition of `\cl@chapter`, adding

```
\RequirePackage{chngcntr}
```

in the proper place (after `\LoadClass`) and, at the end of the class,

```
\if@sequential
  \counterwithout*{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout*{table}{chapter}
  \counterwithout*{equation}{chapter}
\else
  \counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
  \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithin{footnote}{chapter}
  \counterwithin{section}{chapter}
  \counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\fi
```

Comment: Is this a verbatim fix? (Can I implement this myself without fear of breaking the .cls classfile further?)

Comment: Additionally, if so, may I send this code to the owner such that he may make changes if he deems them appropriate?

Comment: @kando I think I interpreted correctly what the class is doing; essentially, `\@elt{chaptercitecount}` will do `\setcounter{chaptercitecount}{0}`, but in a safe way. I'll try and suggest a better fix.

Comment: @kando I added the better fix

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding how to implement the updated fix? Would the first fix still apply? Where would the second fix be placed, and would anything need to be removed?

Comment: @kando The redefinition of `\cl@chapter` should be removed; the better definition of the `chaptercitecount` counter should be as in the previous fix. The new part can go essentially anywhere after `\LoadClass`. At the end, when all relevant counters are surely defined is a good place.

Comment: For clarification: What do you consider to be a redefinition of `\cl@chapter`? (In other words, to remove the redefinition of `\cl@chapter`, should I remove your `\cl@chapter` code and revert to his previous `\cl@chapter` code, or should I remove all usage `\cl@chapter`?)

Comment: @kando Remove from `\def\cl@chapter{` up to the matching `}`.

Comment: Therefore, use: `\def\cl@chapter{}`?  Additionally, the length of the section numbering (excluding chapter numbering) in the table of contents now extends into the section wording.

Comment: @kando ***REMOVE*** from `\def\cl@chapter{` up to the matching `}`.

Comment: Ah! My apologies. I was reading that as **REMOVE** from `\def\cl@chapter{` the internal code (until  the respective `}`).  You meant **REMOVE** starting immediately at `\def\cl@chapter{` through the respective `}`.  Got it.